# quiz game nextquestion if answered skip over

Tags: c#, winforms

i have one problem with my program.

I want to make an auto questionnaire.. like those from getting the car license.

and i want to make a button which when is pressed gets to the next question if i don't know the answer ( like ASK LATER)

i have 26 question. i made the function for the button if clicked question 1 gets the value of question 2. and so on. ( if is 26 gets the value of the question 1).

i want if i already answered to the question not to show again. like if i answered the second question and i am to the first question to skip over to the third question , not showing again the second.

i have a button submit. if clicked gets the next question . i have a label which text is "true" or "false" ( true if isn't answered, and false if answered).

```
if (intrebare.Text == continutintrebare[0].Text && bifat[0].Text =="true")     //#2
{

    intrebare.Text = continutintrebare[1].Text;
    raspunstext[0, 0].Text = "marcheaza sfarsitul zonei unde este interzisa oprirea;";
    raspunstext[0, 1].Text = "marcheaza inceputul zonei unde este interzisa oprirea;";
    raspunstext[0, 2].Text = "marcheaza inceputul zonei unde este interzisa stationarea.";
    raspunstext[0, 0].BackColor = Color.White;
    raspunstext[0, 1].BackColor = Color.White;
    raspunstext[0, 2].BackColor = Color.White;
    imagine.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Chestionare\Chestionar Auto\Chestionar Auto\bin\Debug\imagini chestionar 1\2.jpg");
}
else
{
    if (intrebare.Text == continutintrebare[1].Text && bifat[1].Text == "true")  //#3
        {                
             intrebare.Text = continutintrebare[2].Text;
             raspunstext[0, 0].Text = "indicatorul 1;";
             raspunstext[0, 1].Text = "indicatorul 2;";
             raspunstext[0, 2].Text = "ambele indicatoare.";
             raspunstext[0, 0].BackColor = Color.White;
             raspunstext[0, 1].BackColor = Color.White;
             raspunstext[0, 2].BackColor = Color.White;
             imagine.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Chestionare\Chestionar Auto\Chestionar Auto\bin\Debug\imagini chestionar 1\3.jpg");
        }
        else
        {
             if (intrebare.Text == continutintrebare[2].Text && bifat[2].Text == "true") //#4
             {                                
                  intrebare.Text = continutintrebare[3].Text;
                  raspunstext[0, 0].Text = "autocamionul, autoturismul, motocicleta, troleibuzul;";
                  raspunstext[0, 1].Text = "troleibuzul, autocamionul, motocicleta, autoturismul;";
                  raspunstext[0, 2].Text = "autocamionul, autoturismul, troleibuzul, motocicleta.";
                  raspunstext[0, 0].BackColor = Color.White;
                  raspunstext[0, 1].BackColor = Color.White;
                  raspunstext[0, 2].BackColor = Color.White;
                  imagine.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Chestionare\Chestionar Auto\Chestionar Auto\bin\Debug\imagini chestionar 1\4.jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                 if (intrebare.Text == continutintrebare[3].Text && bifat[3].Text == "true") //#5
                 {                                   
                      intrebare.Text = continutintrebare[4].Text;
                      raspunstext[0, 0].Text = "va continuati drumul, deoarece aveti prioritate de trecere in sensul giratoriu;";
                      raspunstext[0, 1].Text = "opriti si acordati prioritate coloanei cu regim prioritar;";
                      raspunstext[0, 2].Text = "virati la dreapta si parasiti intersectia.";
                      raspunstext[0, 0].BackColor = Color.White;
                      raspunstext[0, 1].BackColor = Color.White;
                      raspunstext[0, 2].BackColor = Color.White;
                 }
```

and so on . this just gets to the next question. if is answered how can skip over?

note intrebare = question.

i want to make it in

```
private void nextquestion_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I would kindly suggest to rephrase your question. It is not easy for anyone (besides you) to understand the code, especially when the variables mean nothing and no messages in English are used. Please, use messages in English and meaningful variable names... I would also remove any code irrelevant to the problem (images and background do not affect the workflow of the program).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it, with basic OOP. Create Question class to represent your individual question

```
public class Question
{
    public int No;
    public string QuestionText;
    public bool isAnswered;
}
```

And in the Main class:

```
public class Main
{
    //your 26 questions stored in this variable
    public List<Question> questions;
    //current question shown
    public Question currentQuestion;

    public Main()
    {
        //initiate List
        questions = new List<Question>();
        //add question no.1
        var question1 = new Question();
        question1.No = 1;           
        question1.QuestionText = "What should I ask here?";
        question1.isAnswered = false;
        questions.Add(question1);
        //TODO: add question no.2 to 26

        //set current question to question no.1
        currentQuestion = question1;
    }

    private void nextquestion_click(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=questions.Count; i++)
        {
            int nextQuestionNo = ((currentQuestion.No+i)%questions.Count);
            if(!questions[nextQuestionNo].isAnswered)
            {
                //next unanswered question found. set that as current question
                //then stop loop
                currentQuestion = questions[nextQuestionNo];
                break;
            }
        }

        //TODO: update the UI to show currentQuestion
    }
}
```

Comment: and in that list how can I add the question ?

Comment: initialize the questions list, and add your questions to the list in Main constructor. I updated the code to show you what i mean. You may also want to move those codes that i put in constructor to other function for example CreateQuesions(), so that you can simply call that function in the constructor.

Comment: Hi @user2997809, if you think this answer is enough, consider to mark it 'Accetpted'. So this question no more displayed in the list of Unanswered question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Question" class and add all necessary properties and make sure you add a property "answered". Then create a generic list of questions (maybe random) into `List<Question>`. Finally query the list (e.g. by Linq) where question is not answered and question-number greater than current question number